# How to copy a folder from /home/kevin to /opt

Tags: drivers, directory

I have a new computer installed with Ubuntu 12.04. Then I want to install wireless driver named `compat-wireless-3.5-3`. Before that, the driver folder to /home/kevin.

I want to install it on `/opt` directory. Before install the driver, i want to copy the driver folder from `/home/kevin` to `/opt`. I try to use ordinary copy (Right Click Copy Paste), but the `paste` is blured. 

After that, i tried using this on terminal:

```
sudo cp /home/kevin/compat-wireless-3.5-3 /opt
```

But I get this error:

```
cp: omitting directory `home/kevin/compat-wireless-3.5-3'
```

What does the command mean? I can't copy the driver folder until now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use the `-r` flag when copying directories, in other words,

```
sudo cp -r /home/kevin/compat-wireless-3.5-3 /opt
```

`-r` means the directory will be copied recursively, content first, then the directory itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo cp -r <source> <dest>
```

Type -
    man cp

for more options!... (:

Answer (score 1):

Enter this line at terminal :

> gksu nautilus

you will nautilus as root and it will open a folder you have a privileges to copy to, so just copy and paste the file inside it

*just be careful when copying files and be sure you won't harm your device as you run as a root as mentioned

Comment: you can add an ampersand at the end so you can close the terminal and keep your nautilus window open:  gksu nautilus &

Comment: also, this might work with other desktop environments as well:
`gksu xdg-open . &`

Answer (score -2):

Or you can try

> sudo cp /home/kevin/compat-wireless-3.5-3/* /opt

The "*" wildcard takes in the folder and the files in compat-wireless-3.5-3 and will copy them to /opt folder.

Comment: This is a bad idea. This will copy the files in compat to /opt. It will not create a /opt/compat folder and will not copy any folders in compat.

Comment: You are right, my bad about that.